# Technical SEO: tell google that pieces of blog are connected

Tags: seo, pagination

I have a few pages of a blog series, for example;

- `/games/finding-games/`
- `/console/installing-games/`
- `/play/starting-a-game/`

All these pages are on different URLs but are a part of one sequential article series.

How would I tell google that? How would I tell google that this is a sequence of articles (i.e. going from start to finish)? Would it work with `rel=next/prev`?

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Do the pages already link to each other?   If so you may not need to do anything else.   Linking like pages together for users also makes search engines see them as related.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using *rel=next/prev* should help.

Google documentation on the topic is very clear. (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en)

The *rel=next/prev* tags help Google to prioritize the first page in SERPS.  However, rel tags are only a hint. My understanding is that if Google feels the second or third page is more relevant to a search query than the first page, it may choose to ignore the first-page prioritization.

For example, assume that a user has already visited the first and second pages a few days back. Now if he deliberately uses keywords describing the third page (may be keywords related to the topic of the third page), Google may choose to show him the third page. (Experienced members can correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. That's how I thought about it as well. But I thought rel=next/prev is only for paginated content (like page 1,2,3,4 etc..).